# How can I get a mongo database's schema through python code

Tags: mongodb

I connect to a remote monggodb through Python, but I don't know what were stored in the db. How can I retrive the schema or structure of the db in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is a shemaless document database. It means there is no schema. Each document can have its own structure, even if they stored in the same collection.

Mongo Atlas has a feature to analyse a collection by sampling documents.

There is an option to specify expected shape of the documents in a collection by defining [validators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/). Mongodb will apply validation rules to new documents, which can provide some structure to the collection. If it is the case, you can retrieve json-schema of the validator with following query:

```
db.getCollectionInfos({name: <collection_name>})[0].options.validator
```

It will return a [$jsonSchema](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-04) object where you can find field names and validation rules.

Comment: thanks! I first call pymongo.MongoClient(uri) and was stuck in this step. For defining validators, what should I do next?

Comment: validators are defined at the time of creating collections. Please read the docs behind the links.